# SharePoint Custom Item Template

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

**How to create an custom item template (eg. content type) that can be only used in SharePoint solutions ?**

Answer (score 0):

Rex - if I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to customize an app on a sharepoint page, and then make that customized version a template so you can add it as content to other sharepoint pages?

If so, get your customized app the way you want it to be as a template, then while in the Settings for that app, there should be a link under "Permissions and Management" that says "Save [content type] as template".  After you have named and saved the template, you should see it as an option in the list the next time you go to "add an app".

Comment: I meant to say, Suppose I have created an empty SharePoint solution, and in that I add one item(Eg. Content type) that item I wanna create which is customized by me and I can provide it to developers to use in their solutions.